# How to get the column names of a DataFrame GroupBy object?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get the column names of a GroupBy object? The object does not supply a columns propertiy. I can aggregate the object first or extract a DataFrame with the get_group()-method but this is either a power consuming hack or error prone if there are dismissed columns (strings for example).

Comment: What about example?

Comment: This works for me: `df.groupby(col_name).apply(lambda g: g.columns)`. What version of pandas are you on?

Comment: Are you trying to get the column names of a DataFrame from a groupby object created on that DataFrame? Why don't you directly check the column names of the DataFrame?

Comment: @IanS: Thanks, that works. I find it still kind uf ugly, but I suppose there is no 'clean' way if the columns of the DataFrame ar not exposed directly. Could you please provide an answer? If there is no other option in the near future I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @ayhan: I am writing a function which gets a GroupBy object as an argument and don't want to pass the names also.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looking at the source code of `__getitem__`, it seems that you can get the column names with

```
g.obj.columns
```

where g is the groupby object. Apparently `g.obj` links to the DataFrame.

Comment: Nice idea of looking at the source.

Answer (score 3):

As Ayhan said,
g.obj.columns does return columns,  but of the dataframe.
The group object columns returned by
g.any().columns is not the same.

Specifically,  g.any().columns does NOT include the columns used to create the groupby whereas g.obj.columns does.

So it depends on your use model for the result if this difference concerns you.  In my case, I can be a bit less pedantic,  but for a distributable piece of code, you may want to be precise.

```
In [109]: ww.grp.any().columns
Out[109]: 
Index(['inode', 'size', 'drvid', 'path', 'hash', 'ftype', 'id', 'md5',
       'parent', 'top'],
      dtype='object')

In [110]: ww.grp.any().index.name
Out[110]: 'file'

In [111]: ww.grp.obj.columns
Out[111]: 
Index(['inode', 'size', 'drvid', 'path', 'hash', 'ftype', 'file', 'id', 'md5',
       'parent', 'top'],
      dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to get the [indices](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.indices.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.indices) attribute, which is a dictionary. The keys of that dictionary are tuples (if more than one level, otherwise strings) giving the grouped levels' values.

Examples:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
...                     [
...                         [1, 2, 3], 
...                         [4, 5, 6], 
...                         [7, 8, 9]
...                     ], 
...                     index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples( [('i', 1), ('ii', 2), ('iii', 3)] ),
...                     columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples( [('A', 'a'), ('B', 'b'), ('C', 'c')] )
... )

>>> df.columns.names = ['UPPER', 'lower']

>>> df
UPPER  A  B  C
lower  a  b  c
i   1  1  2  3
ii  2  4  5  6
iii 3  7  8  9

>>> grps = df.groupby(axis='columns', level=['UPPER','lower'])

>>> grps.indices
{('A', 'a'): array([0]), ('B', 'b'): array([1]), ('C', 'c'): array([2])}

>>> grps.indices.keys()
dict_keys([('A', 'a'), ('B', 'b'), ('C', 'c')])

>>> grps2.indices
{'A': array([0]), 'B': array([1]), 'C': array([2])}

>>> grps2.indices.keys()
dict_keys(['A', 'B', 'C'])
```